# Discrete variables with constraint on sum - How many possible cases?

Tags: combinatorics

Given n variables 
$$X_1,..., X_n \in [1, 2, ..., k-1, k] $$ 
(Each variable has takes an integer value between 1 and k)

and the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k$

**What is the total number of distinct possibilities for $(X_1, ..., X_n)$?**

Without the constraint, the solution is $k^N$.

With the constraint and n=2, the solution is $k$

I am stuck at solving the general case.

Comment: I have just seen this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807905/find-the-number-tuples-such-that-all-elements-are-distinct-and-are-whole-numbers, which is basically the same problem, but has no answer yet

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is a question about _integer partitions_. I haven't read yours carefully. In general, these are very hard problems and don't usually have nice closed form solutions. You can start reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) . Then perhaps   search the web for that topic, perhaps with the adjectives _bounded_ or _distinct_ parts. You'll find links to wolfram, and to research papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be a condition that $ n<k$ and other conditions like whether we need to assign some value to each variable or it can be left empty, need to be specifically mentioned.

Assuming that each variable needs to be assigned a value and $n<k$ the no. of solution will be same as coefficient of $x^{k-n}$ in expression $(1-x)^{-n}$
which is $^{k-1}C_{n-1}$

I will explain, if you require.

Comment: We actually denote the values, which can be given to these variables in your question, as power of x. So, you have $x^i$ for i=1,2,3,...k. So, for $X_1,X_2,..X_n$ you have  $(x+x^2+x^3...x^k)^n$ . And we seek coefficient of $x^k$ in this expression.

Comment: I suggest you to read binomial coefficients & theorem before attempting this question. May be you will understand more.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked your solution programmatically, and it looks correct: 
`k <- 157; n <- 4; counter <- 0; for(x1 in 1:(k-(n-1))){ for(x2 in 1:(k-x1-(n-2))){ for(x3 in 1:(k-x1-x2-(n-3))){ x4 <- k-x1-x2-x3; counter <- counter+1 } } }; print(counter==ncol(combn(k-1,n-1))))`